# what's wrong with this macro, keep getting the same error

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to make a macro to automate the creation of a graph form one of the output for a machine. I have written the steps down and practiced them many times buy keep getting an error and don't know what it means or how to fix it. I have # the line that my errors appears. I think the rest of the code is good. I used the macro recorder to create this.

here is the code:

```
Macro4 Macro
'

'
    Range("I2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$W$1086").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="<700000"
    Range("G99:I165").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("G1:L1083").Select
    ExecuteExcel4Macro "(FALSE,227,4)"
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Raw Data'!$G$1:$L$1083")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft -482
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop 113
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleWidth 3.2611111111, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleHeight 1.1782407407, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleWidth 1.0340715503, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleHeight 2.6895874263, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveChart.Axes("xlCategory").Select
```

## this line below is my problem

```
    Selection.Border.Color = RGB(, , )    

    Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelSpacing = 1
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelSpacing = 100
    ActiveChart.Axes("xlValue").Select
    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue)
        .MinimumScale = -90
        .Crosses = xlCustom
    End With
    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue)
        .MaximumScale = 30
        .Crosses = xlCustom
    End With
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).AxisGroup = 2
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 2
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Range("A1047").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.Paste
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "017306T11FluCandida            "
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "017306T11FluCandida            "
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 31).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignLeft
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 30).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 18
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(31, 1).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoTrue
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 18
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    Range("A1086").Select
```

Comment: You say you're receiving an error. Where is it?

Comment: Is the line  `Selection.Border.Color = RGB(, , ) `   you refer to?. If yes, try to pass 3 numbers for R,G,B (0-255)

Comment: Does it matter what numbers I add?

Comment: RGB is short for **R**ed, **G**reen, **B**lue. Each integer from 1-255 represents the amount of each tint in the resulting color.

Comment: Ok i added some numbers to it and ran it again. Of course its giving me another bug in this line: ExecuteExcel4Macro "(FALSE,227,4)" is this also another color thing and should i change the false to a number. the line above it is where i highlight a large section of cells to create the line graph.

Comment: I have all my steps written down and I have an idea of what certain things are but these random line of code that seem to mean nothing is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call `ExecuteExcel4Macro "(FALSE,227,4)"` - the argument for this Method should be in the format `Function(argument1, argument2, ..)`,depending on the macro function you are trying to call.  However, you seem to have omitted the Function name itself.

Essentially, you are telling the computer "do something with these values", but not giving it any suggestion as to what to do.  So, it (quite naturally) objects, and throws an error.

More info on the Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro Method is available on MSDN:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-executeexcel4macro-method-excel  (Just hit F1 in VBA when you have your typing-cursor on the function you want to look up)

Comment: I am still getting odd errors so I've decided a different approach. I'm going to divide my macro steps into different separate sections and record each one individually and make sure they run as is on the sheet and then Im going to copy and paste them together and see where the problem is. Im thinking that im clicking something I shouldnt in one of the sections or the transition from one task like cleaning up the data and then making the graph is having issues. I'm going to try this as soon as my experiment schedule clears up. Thank you for your help.